# Instantiating a button in swift (Probably easy to fix)

Tags: swift, uibutton

I haven't used swift in a few months and the documentation is confusing me. I have a button on my storyboard that I control+click+dragged over to the ViewController to create an @IBOutlet. I can not figure out why, but every time I open the app it crashes, but it builds fine. It doesn't crash without the instantiating of the button but I cannot for the life of me figure out how I did it wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The hollowed circle on the left of the IBOutlet line indicates that there is no connection.

There are a couple of things you need to check:

1. Select the view controller scene in the storyboard and open the Identity inspector from the right sidebar (you can hover over the icons in the top and the tooltip should popup to show you what the inspector is named). Make sure the class name is correct, HomeViewController.
2. Select the button from the storyboard and from the right sidebar, select the connections inspector, make sure the referencing outlet is empty and there are no yellow warnings in all the connections. If you find any connections with warnings, hover over them to make the X button visible and click it to remove the connection.
3. Try to click and drag from the hollow circle next to the IBOutlet line to the button in the storyboard. The circle should be filled if the connection is successful.